# jquery-watermark plugin and HTML5 email input type not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-plugins, html, email-validation

[diveintohtml5](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#type-email) says it's okay to start using the email form type. So I am trying it out on one of my forms. I'm using jQuery and a plugin called [jquery-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/). It makes the placeholder element work across browsers. The plugin still works on Firefox 3.6 but on Opera 10.61 and Chrome 6 the placeholder isn't rendered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('form input#comment_email').watermark('email (optional)');
</script>
```

is used to display the watermark/placeholder.

Rails 3 outputs this:

```
<input id="comment_email" name="comment[email]" size="30" type="email" />
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the jquery-watermark plugin only selects certain input types to watermark. All you should have to do is tweak this line in jquery.watermark.js:

```
selWatermarkAble = ":text,:password,:search,textarea",
```

to include the new email type:

```
selWatermarkAble = ":text,:password,:search,:email,textarea",
```

Comment: When I set it to `selWatermarkAble=":text,:password,:search,:email,textarea",`
Opera stops rendering all the watermarks. If I use
`selWatermarkAble=":text,:password,:search,email,textarea",` the watermarks work again in Opera excluding the email field which defeats the point because Opera is the only desktop browser that actually validates email addresses. The other browsers render the email watermark though. When I use `selWatermarkAble=":text,:password,:search,:email,textarea",` all browsers work excluding Opera which doesn't render any watermarks... what's going here?

Comment: I suspect it needs to be input[type=email], not :email.

Comment: There is an issue logged to include support for HTML5 input types in the next version of the watermark plugin - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/issues/detail?id=54

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean the placeholder texts in inputs?
There is an alternative solution: HTML 5 Placeholders, and Watermark is a good fallback to browsers that do not support placeholders.

```
 $('input[placeholder]').each(function() {
   $(this).watermark($(this).attr('placeholder'));
 })
```

(note: I did not test that code!)

(EDIT: See also http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#input-placeholder )

Comment: You might also, given the implementation of watermark(), temporarily switch the type to "text" and then back again.